# Finding the mean of nuisance columns in DataFrame error

Tags: python, pandas, mean

```
      id gender status dept  var1  var2  salary
0   P001      M     FT   DS   2.0   8.0     NaN
1   P002      F     PT   FS   3.0   NaN    54.0
2   P003      M    NaN  AWS   5.0   5.0    59.0
3   P004      F     FT  AWS   NaN   8.0   120.0
4   P005      M     PT   DS   7.0  11.0    58.0
5   P006      F     PT  NaN   1.0   NaN    75.0
6   P007      M     FT   FS   NaN   NaN     NaN
7   P008      F    NaN   FS  10.0   2.0   136.0
8   P009      M     PT  NaN  14.0   3.0    60.0
9   P010      F     FT   DS   NaN   7.0   125.0
10  P011      M    NaN  AWS   6.0   9.0     NaN

print(df.mean())

FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  print(df.mean())
```

when corrected my code as :

```
print(df.mean(numeric_only=True))
```

I solve it , without an error.

Is there any other way to solve it ?

Comment: Why and how else would you want to *solve* it?

Comment: This could be due to using `numeric_only=None` in newer version of `pandas` where it is deprecated. Is your `pandas` version >=1.35?

Answer (score 20):

No, there's no other way to solve it. Using `numeric_only=True` is the right way.

You're getting that warning because there are some columns that contain **strings**, but `df.mean()` only works with columns that contain numbers (floats, ints, nan, etc.).

Using `numeric_only=True` causes `df.mean()` to ignore columns that contain non-numbers, and only calculate the mean for columns that only contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: It is not clear how this solves the problem. Please provide enough explanation and link to resources or additional documentation to support your answer.