# "FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions" warning when using df.mean()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   col1   col2 col3
0     1   True  abc
1     2  False  def
2     3   True  ghi
```

When I run `df.mean()`, it shows a warning:

```
>>> df.mean()
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
col1    2.000000
col2    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

How do I solve this warning?

Comment: Note: this question is one of a few canonicals I intend to post regarding common pandas warnings/errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the mean of nuisance columns in DataFrame error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897794/finding-the-mean-of-nuisance-columns-in-dataframe-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numeric functions such as `mean`, `median`, `sem`, `skew`, etc., only support dealing with numeric values. If you look at the data types of your columns...

```
>>> df.dtypes
col1     int64
col2      bool
col3    object
dtype: object
```

...you can see that the dtype of `col1` is `int64`, which `mean` can handle, because it's numeric. Likewise, the dtype of `col2` is `bool`, which Python, pandas, and numpy essentially treat as ints, so `mean` treats `col2` as if it only contains `1` (for `True`) and `0` for `False`.

The dtype of `col3`, however, is `object`, the default dtype for strings, which is basically a generic type to encapsulate *any* type of data that pandas can't understand. Since it's not numeric, `mean` has no idea how to deal with it. (After all, how would you compute the mean of `abc` and `def`?)

There are a few ways to solve this problem, but "ignoring it" isn't one of them, because, as the warning indicates, in a future version of pandas, this warning will become an error that will stop your code from running.

1. Use `numeric_only=True`. This will cause `mean` to skip columns that aren't numeric — `col3` in this case:

   ```
   >>> df.mean(numeric_only=True)
   col1    2.000000
   col2    0.666667
   dtype: float64
   ```

   (Notice how `col3` is omitted).
2. Select only the columns you need to operate on:

   ```
   >>> df[['col1', 'col2']].mean()
   col1    2.000000
   col2    0.666667
   dtype: float64
   ```

Comment: I have the same issue and am only selecting known numeric columns using the manner of your solution#2. I still get the warning in Pandas 1.4.4.